# undefined variable image size in theme-woocommerce.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, undefined, image-size

I'm having a problem within the wordpress / woocommerce environment.
On my single product pages the products within the section "related products" gets the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: image_size in /home/deb74750n2/domains/seatsandmore.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/themify-shoppe/woocommerce/theme-woocommerce.php on line 73

This is the line of code at line 72 till 76:

```
    if($width || $height){
        $attr =  'ignore=true&'.$image_size.'w=' . $width . '&h=' . $height;

        if($src){
            $attr.= '&src='.$src;
        }
```

I've tried various possible solutions but I keep getting this error. If you know a possible solution I would love to hear it.

Kind regards,
Melvin

Comment: `if($width || $height||$image_size){`  Just a suggestion

Comment: Either that of create the variable `$image_size`

Comment: Unfortunatelly that didn't seem to work

Comment: What didnt work? try `if($width && $height && isset($image_size))` as you need all 3 to execute the statment inside the if

Comment: This is related to a custom woocommerce template included by your theme and you should contact the theme author's support pages instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the last thing you wrote worked.